# Take hexadecimal value in a variable in C from binary file

Tags: c

```
printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
gets(file_name);
fp = fopen(file_name,"rb");
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF  && loop)
{
    printf("value of ch is %x\n",ch);
    loop--;               
}
```

I have a binary file and I read it with "rb" permission.and printing its value in hexadecimal but if I am taking this value in a array for other purpose then it shows different value when I printing the array value which is not same as I printing in this above code.

Please help me how can I store the data (Hexadecimal) of binary file in the array.

Comment: You explain your question so clearly...

Comment: Please don't "edit" your question to replace it with a completely different question, especially after someone's already posted an answer.  I've reverted that change.  If you have a different question to ask, post another question and leave this one alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data itself is not "hexadecimal", it's just a single character (byte, typically) of bits from the file.

You can choose to print it in hexadecimal, or any other format. You can do that regardless if you have the value in an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

it should be written as

```
const int t_huffman_env_1_5dB[][2] =
{
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFD6},
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFD7},
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFD8},
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFD9},
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFDA},
    {0x00000012, 0x0003FFDB},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFB8},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFB9},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBA},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBB},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBC},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBD},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBE},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFBF},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC0},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC1},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC2},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC3},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC4},
    {0x00000013, 0x0007FFC5}
};
```

Comment: @Petter: OP self-answered his totally changed question. Original q is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24572324/3).